# dlmwrite for specific rows and columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2D data for 10x10 matrices, and it looks like this 
[here is the table](http://i46.tinypic.com/2ex4tv6.gif)

However, data is updating and append every dt calculation, therefore I would like to reorganize and write it for specific columns , you may see this table in [link](http://i49.tinypic.com/5v83sy.gif)

I use normally those codes to write

```
      t=t+dt;

    if ss==2000
     dlmwrite('d:\Model_Results_Theta.txt', Tnew,'-append');
    ss=0;
    end
```

Could you recommend me any different way to organize the data based on the specific rows and columns using the matlab codes? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Have a look at reshape: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: Alternatively you can call `dlmwrite` with an 'offset column' (5th argument) - i.e. `dlmwrite(filename, Tnew, 'DLM', 0, numberOfTimesCalled)`, where `numberOfTimesCalled` is the zero-based column offset index.